# GeckoWebBrowser in vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, gecko

I'am trying to run JavaScript code inside GeckoWebBrowser

my current code is :

```
 GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:void(" + TextBox2.Text + ")")
```

textbox2.text contains :

```
alert('test');
```

it run normally , but when I try to use multiline JavaScript
example :

```
var r = confirm("Press a button");
if (r == true) {
    x = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

the browser run nothing , Please Help Me  
 
Thanks

Comment: I don't know about the GeckoWebBrowser, but the Microsoft WebBrowser control has a `Document` property, through which you can access an `InvokeScript` method designed specifically for running javascript in the page, rather than using the `Navigate` method - perhaps GeckoWebBrowser has similar functionality?

Comment: no I tried that  it will dump an error in vb.net consol

Answer (score 0):

It's probably generating a javascript error that your browser control is not revealing.  When I create a simple page to reproduce what you're describing, clicking the link in Chrome gives:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(var r = confirm('Press a button');
if (r == true) {
    x = 'You pressed OK!';
} else {
    x = 'You pressed Cancel!';
    })">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```